# Dropdown rendering outside page and not closing when window width increases

Tags: html, css, jquery-chosen

I'm using Harvest's "chosen" plugin, and it's working fine until the browser window increases too far in width-- then for some reason it calculates that left should be -9000 and renders off screen.

Furthermore, I can no longer get it to close by clicking outside of the dropdown area.

Screenshot below-- what can be seen of the dropdown is circled in red. Has anyone else run into this problem?

[image: dropdown rendering off screen]

Comment: I thought Chosen was a separate jquery plugin, is it really part of bootstrap?

Comment: AHH you're right, it's not! Hopefully I can remove tags.... Thanks for pointing that out! The css is so similar I forgot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized what's going on.

When you're outside of the input/dropdown, the dropdown is still rendered, but *given a left of -9000px*.

My browser width is currently about 9400 px.

Still don't actually know why it's not closing, though.

EDIT: edited the src to use show/hide instead of left and it works now....